# Java program cannot find symbol nextInt() or nextLine()

Tags: java, arrays

Here is my code that I've written so far....basically I want to enter a first name (eventually a last name and a GPA) and have it saved in a 2D array.  I'm having trouble with adding the user input into the array.  Under public static void addstudent is this a correct method for adding to an array?  If so, why do I keep getting the error that nextInt is not found?  I also get that if I change it to nextLine or just next().  Thanks for the help!

```
import static java.lang.System.in;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Project1 {

public static void main (String[] args){
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String [][] students = new String [50][3];
System.out.println("Menu");
System.out.println("A) Add Student");
System.out.println("D) Delete Student");
System.out.println("L) List Students");
String opt = input.nextLine();
char optc = opt.charAt(0);
switch(optc) {
    case 'A': addStudent(students);
    case 'D': deleteStudent(students);
    case 'L': listStudent(students);
}
}
public static void addStudent(String students[][]) {
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); {
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
     System.out.println("Please Enter first name"); 
     students[i] = in.nextInt();
 }
```

Comment: Your Scanner variable is named `input`, not `in`. So `input.nextInt()` not `in.nextInt()`. The lesson is to carefully proof read the code that the error is telling you is wrong.

Comment: When I change it to input.nextInt()  it says "Int cannot be converted to String[].

Comment: That is a completely separate problem, unrelated to the question that you're asking here.

Comment: Your students variable is a 2-dimensional array of String, and you're trying to assign a String to an array of String. The error is again telling you *exactly* what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Ok got it!  Thanks!

Comment: The compiler already is telling you this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm pretty new to JAVA.  So would I need to create a new string and then assign it to my first name input?

Answer (score 0):

Sooner or later, you're going to want to refactor your 2d array into an array of objects like so:

```
public class Student{
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public float GPA;

    public Student(String fn, String ln, float g){
        firstName = fn;
        lastName = ln;
        GPA = g;
    }
}

public class project1{
//note that the variables are class-scope, not function-scope
    Student stus[50];
.
.
.
}
```

In the meantime, you're trying to access a 2d array, not a 1d array, and you need to accept as input a string, not an int, so this line:

```
     students[i] = in.nextInt();
```

should look like this:

```
    students[i][0] = input.nextLine();
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  That makes complete sense!